# Python: Descending order and just 3 objects has a high value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, object

I have an array object like that, Not sort value, I want descending order and just 3 objects has a high value:

```
[{'id': 1, 'value': 3}, 
{'id': 2, 'value': 6},
{'id': 3, 'value': 8}, 
{'id': 4, 'value': 8}, 
{'id': 5, 'value': 10},
{'id': 6, 'value': 9},
{'id': 7, 'value': 8},
{'id': 8, 'value': 4},
{'id': 9, 'value': 5}]
```

I want result is descending order and just 3 objects have a high value, like this

```
[{'id': 5, 'value': 10},
{'id': 6, 'value': 9},
{'id': 7, 'value': 8},
{'id': 3, 'value': 8}, 
{'id': 4, 'value': 8},]
```

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to include a [mre] of your own attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: `obj.sort( key = lambda k: -k['value'])`.  Just do a normal sort, specifying the key you want.  Making it negative will sort in descending order.

Comment: Not sort value, I want descending order and just 3 objects has a high value

Answer (score -1):

```
t = [{'id': 1, 'value': 3}, 
{'id': 2, 'value': 6},
{'id': 3, 'value': 8}, 
{'id': 4, 'value': 8}, 
{'id': 5, 'value': 10},
{'id': 6, 'value': 9},
{'id': 7, 'value': 8}]

newlist = sorted(t, key=lambda d: d['value'])
newlist.reverse()
print(newlist[:3])
# [{'id': 5, 'value': 10}, {'id': 6, 'value': 9}, {'id': 7, 'value': 8}]
```

[More info about list slicing](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/list-slicing)

[More info about `reverse()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/reverse)

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: Close.  Note that he wants descending order.

Comment: I want descending order and just 3 objects has a high value

Comment: Thanks for the edit, But I have 3 objects have a value:8, and I also want them in my result